# Why does reading from pipe block the process?

Tags: .net, ipc, named-pipes

I have two processes ( both `.NET Framework` applications) and i am trying to communicate using `Named Pipes`
The client connects to the pipe , but when it tries to `ReadAsync` the message sent by the server, it starts waiting indifinetly , **even though the server has already sent a message !!**

What surprises me is that if i close the `Server` app the `Client`  finally **continues** to the next line of code (after the `ReadAsync` line), having read **0** bytes.

Is there anything i must to on the server after `WriteAsync`-ing the payload? Do i need to flush or anything ?

**Server**

```
static async Task Main(string[] args) {

         var server = new NamedPipeServerStream(
             "somePipe",
              PipeDirection.InOut, 
              2, 
              PipeTransmissionMode.Message
              );

         await server.WaitForConnectionAsync();

         using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(server)) {
              using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(server)) {

                 await writer.WriteAsync("Hello from server"); 

                 char[] buffer = new char[20];
                 var read = await reader.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                }
         }
}
```

**Client**

```
 static async Task Main() {

    NamedPipeClientStream client = new NamedPipeClientStream(
             ".",
             "somePipe",
             PipeDirection.InOut,
             PipeOptions.Asynchronous);

    await client.ConnectAsync();

    try {
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(client)) {
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(client)) {

          var buffer = new char[20];
          int readChars = await reader.ReadAsync(buffer, 0,buffer.Length); //starts waiting indifinetly , until i close the Server

          await writer.WriteAsync("From Client");

        }
     }
     } catch (Exception ex) {

       throw;
     }
}
```

**Update**
It seems using the `NamedPipeServerStream` directly to write instead of the `StreamWriter` on the server side makes the client get the data !

**Server Changes**

```
byte[] data=Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello from server");
server.WriteAsync(data,0,data.Length);
```

**P.S**
However using again the `server` to `ReadAsync` blocks the server.So there is a problem when wrapping the `NamedPipeServerStream` and `ClientStream` into `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter`.

Comment: `StreamWriter` has an internal buffer. Have you tried explicitly calling `Flush()` on the writer after writing your message and/or setting `AutoFlush = true`?

Comment: I have tried using `Flush` before reading and writing.

Comment: Can you try to add `.ConfigureAwait(false)` to the end of all your await(ed) calls?

Comment: It seems it works without problems adding `.ConfigureAwait` one my `ConnectAsync` of the client  and on the `WriteAsync` of the server.Could you further explain ? I have not used this before and i do not understand the behaviour.It seems even `Flush` is not needed anymore.

Comment: @Simon Mourier post the answer and i will accept it.It solved my problem , thank you very much. Also if you could explain why i need the `ConfigureAwait(false)` i would be extremely grateful or perhaps why don't the `StreamReader` and `Writer` work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This blocking/lock issue is caused by the code that's generated undercovers by the async/await syntactic sugar.
If you don't add `ConfigureAwait(false)`, the compiler generates something that's cool for a UI application (UI is a general term, could be ASP.NET - not core - , WPF, Winforms, etc.), but that can be deadly otherwise.

A *lot* has beew written on this matter:

[Don't Block on Async Code](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html)

quoted:

> There are two best practices [...] that avoid this situation:
>
> - In your “library” async methods, use ConfigureAwait(false) wherever
>     possible.
> - Don’t block on Tasks; use async all the way down.

[Parallel Computing - It's All About the SynchronizationContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598924.aspx)

[Best practice to call ConfigureAwait for all server-side code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13489065/best-practice-to-call-configureawait-for-all-server-side-code)

[Should I call ConfigureAwait(false) on every awaited operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43423709/should-i-call-configureawaitfalse-on-every-awaited-operation)

So, the simplest solution is to add `ConfigureAwait(false)` *everywhere* in your code that is not known to run in the UI, or use `async` *everywhere* (never block on any task ever in your whole code, really everywhere, including in code you don't own).

IMHO, this is ridiculous... I personally use a Visual Studio extension that yells at me, if I forget to add it behind every `async` call :-)

Note there are some alternatives, for example: 
[An alternative to ConfigureAwait(false) everywhere](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benwilli/2017/02/09/an-alternative-to-configureawaitfalse-everywhere/)